# Sending signal to a forked process that calls exec()

Tags: c, shell, unix, signals, exec

I have a simple C program that forks a process and call exec to run a command as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int fork_process(int sleep_interval) {
   char cmd[30];

   pid_t pid = fork();       
   if (pid > 0) {
       return pid;
   }
   else if (pid < 0) {
        printf("At parent. Couldn't create a child process!\n");
        return pid;
   }
   else { 
        sprintf(cmd, "sleep %d; %s", sleep_interval, "gzip a > a.gz");
        execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", cmd, (char *) 0);
   }
}

int main () {
   pid_t pid = fork_process(400);

   sleep (10);
   kill(pid, SIGTERM);

   return 1;
}
```

When I run this program, I notice that `sh` internally forks a process to run `sleep 400`:

```
$ps x
  1428 pts/80   S+     0:00 ./kill_prog
  1429 pts/80   S+      0:00 sh -c sleep 400; gzip a > a.gz
  1430 pts/80   S+      0:00 sleep 400
```

Now, when the `SIGTERM` signal is sent in the program to the child process through its pid (`1429` here), I notice that the child process terminates but not the process executing `sleep 400` (pid `1430`). In other words, the process executing `sleep 400` becomes a zombie until it completes.

How do I send a kill signal such that the signal is propagated to processes forked within the child process? I tried using the process group id in `kill` as `kill(-1*pid, SIGTERM)` but to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured a fix for the problem above. It was a matter of two small changes.

I add to do this in the parent after forking a child:

```
pid_t pid = fork();   
if (pid > 0) {
   // Make child process the leader of its own process group. This allows
   // signals to also be delivered to processes forked by the child process.
   setpgid(childpid, 0); 
   return pid;
}
```

And finally, send the signal to the whole process group:

```
// Send signal to process group of child which is denoted by -ve value of child pid.
// This is done to ensure delivery of signal to processes forked within the child. 
kill((-1*pid), SIGTERM);
```

Comment: You should also call `setpgid(0, 0)` in the child, so that the process group is set even if the child performed `execlp()` before the parent's `setpgid()` call. Note that the call in the parent is also still needed so that the process group is set before `kill()` even if the child process is delayed for a long time before its `setpgid()` call.

Comment: If you perform the operation this way, it works for almost all situations, however, it may prevent things like bash from operating because `setsid` can't run... If you need that, you can let the process `setsid` itself and then you can call something like `kill( tcgetpgrp( ptsfilehandle ), SIGINT );` to get it to send the actual kill.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple: just add a SIGTERM signal handler to the process:

- http://rackerhacker.com/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/

Comment: Good point. I had a slightly similar thought - what if I used SIGKILL (which can't take a signal handler) instead of SIGTERM in kill(). But using SIGKILL had the same observations as above. So, in that case, what do I need to do to get the signal delivered to all the processes shown above?

Comment: Hi - I wasn't saying "SIGKILL".  I was saying "you've gotta make your own signal handler!"  Two other things you might want to research: Linux [process groups](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpgrp), and [killpg](http://linux.die.net/man/2/killpg)

Comment: paulsm4, thanks for pointing out the two links. And I understood what you were saying earlier. I was trying to point that writing a signal handler wouldn't solve the problem for all cases. For example - this approach won't help if I need to send a SIGKILL. And I tried sending the signal to the process group using kill (killpg() is a wrapper that calls kill(-pid,signo)) but that didn't work as noted in the question.

Comment: Note that this `SIGTERM` signal handler will have to be written in shell, using `trap`. To make it work, you have to put the `sleep` in the background and `wait` for it so the shell runs trap handlers while waiting, except on shells that have `sleep` as a builtin.